# Undefined functions while compiling linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to work with linux softirq. A have a simple program that uses linux system calls defined in `linux/interrupt.h`:

```
//
// Created by kivi on 24.09.16.
//

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>

#define SHARED_IRQ 17

static int irq = SHARED_IRQ, my_dev_id, irq_counter = 0;
module_param( irq, int, S_IRUGO );

/* The interrupt handler */ 
static irqreturn_t xxx_interrupt( int irq, void *dev_id ) { 
    printk( KERN_INFO "In the top-half: counter = %d\n", irq_counter );
   raise_softirq( XXX_SOFT_IRQ ); 
   return IRQ_HANDLED; 
}

/* The bottom half */ 
void xxx_analyze(struct softirq_action *str) { 
    irq_counter++;
    printk( KERN_INFO "In the bottom-half: counter = %d\n", irq_counter );
}

static int __init my_init( void ) {
    request_irq( irq, xxx_interrupt, 0, "xxx", NULL );
    open_softirq( XXX_SOFT_IRQ, xxx_analyze); 
    printk( KERN_INFO "Successfully set softirq handler on IRQ %d\n", irq );
    return 0;
}

static void __exit my_exit( void ) {
    synchronize_irq( irq );
    free_irq( irq, &my_dev_id );
    printk( KERN_INFO "Successfully unloading, irq_counter = %d\n", irq_counter );
}

module_init( my_init );
module_exit( my_exit );
MODULE_LICENSE( "GPL v2" );
```

When I try to compile this module I get linker errors that functions `open_softirq()` and `raise_softirq()` are not defined:

```
kivi@kivi-pc:~/sp_labs/irq_exc/softirq$ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.7.5-custom/build M=/home/kivi/sp_labs/irq_exc/softirq modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/kivi/Downloads/linux-4.7.5'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "open_softirq" [/home/kivi/sp_labs/irq_exc/softirq/softirq.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "raise_softirq" [/home/kivi/sp_labs/irq_exc/softirq/softirq.ko] undefined!
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kivi/Downloads/linux-4.7.5'
```

The interesting thing is that functions `request_irq()` e.t.c. are also defined in `interrupt.h` file, but they don't cause any problem.

Here is my Makefile:

```
obj-m += softirq.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

So can anyone help me please with my problem.

P.S. i googled my problem and found some advice that I should add `KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS=*module path*/Module.symvers` when compiling, but it didn't help.

Comment: I am no LKM guru, but last time I wrote a kernel module I had a similar problem and I had to set some special `#define` in order to link symbols marked with `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL()`

Comment: Can you please give more detailed description how to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `open_softirq` and `raise_softirq` functions are not *exported*, and so you cannot link to them. Exported functions are marked with the `EXPORT_SYMBOL` or `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL` macros.

On the other side, you will see how `request_irq` is exported (actually, it is [inlined](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/interrupt.h#L144) to `request_threaded_irq`, which [is](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/irq/manage.c#L1681) exported).

You can find plenty of information about the `EXPORT_SYMBOL` macros. For instance, [here's](https://www.quora.com/What-happens-when-you-use-EXPORT_SYMBOL-in-the-Linux-kernel/answer/Robert-Love-1?srid=yil0) an explanation from Robert Love.

Now, you are probably wondering why those functions aren't exported. Well, softirqs are a low-level mechanism, meant to be used by other higher-level facilities, so the intention is to prevent its usage in non-core kernel code.

Modules should use higher-level facilities instead (timers for instance).

It is interesting to check how many softirqs users the kernel has.

```
$ git grep open_softirq
block/blk-softirq.c:    open_softirq(BLOCK_SOFTIRQ, blk_done_softirq);
include/linux/interrupt.h:extern void open_softirq(int nr, void (*action)(struct softirq_action *));
kernel/rcu/tiny.c:      open_softirq(RCU_SOFTIRQ, rcu_process_callbacks);
kernel/rcu/tree.c:      open_softirq(RCU_SOFTIRQ, rcu_process_callbacks);
kernel/sched/fair.c:    open_softirq(SCHED_SOFTIRQ, run_rebalance_domains);
kernel/softirq.c:void open_softirq(int nr, void (*action)(struct softirq_action *))
kernel/softirq.c:       open_softirq(TASKLET_SOFTIRQ, tasklet_action);
kernel/softirq.c:       open_softirq(HI_SOFTIRQ, tasklet_hi_action);
kernel/time/timer.c:    open_softirq(TIMER_SOFTIRQ, run_timer_softirq);
lib/irq_poll.c: open_softirq(IRQ_POLL_SOFTIRQ, irq_poll_softirq);
net/core/dev.c: open_softirq(NET_TX_SOFTIRQ, net_tx_action);
net/core/dev.c: open_softirq(NET_RX_SOFTIRQ, net_rx_action);
```

Just 12!

This pattern repeats across the kernel: stuff that maintainers consider *lowish-level* is not exported and meant for core kernel code only.

Comment: Can you please give me some example how to use it for linux kernel functions. I googled something and all I found is examples for exporting your own symbols from module. I tried to add `EXPORT_SYMBOL` for `raise_softirq` and `open_softirq`, but now I get compile errors.

Comment: Also, google says, that if symbol is already exported somewhere with `EXPORT_SYMBOL`, then it's available in all kernel modules. `open_softirq` and `raise_softirq` are already exported in `kernel/softirq.c`. So I don't really understand what is happening.

Comment: First of all, *no* `open/raise_sofirq` are *not* exported. The `open_softirq` export was removed ages ago back in 2006, see here https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/7/11/264.

Comment: Second, the build error is maybe the `XXX_SOFT_IRQ` not being defined anywhere? Or otherwise, point me at your build error. But it would have nothing to do with this particular question ;)

Comment: I manually added XXX_SOFT_IRQ into `interrupts.h` file and rebuilded kernel. 
THere are two errors when compiling my module:
include/linux/export.h:63:39: error: section attribute cannot be specified for local variables
__visible const struct kernel_symbol __ksymtab_##sym \ ;  
                              
include/linux/export.h:63:39: error: declaration of ‘__ksymtab_raise_softirq’ with no linkage follows extern declaration
__visible const struct kernel_symbol __ksymtab_##sym \

I can't understand what they are mean

Comment: I think you must be doing something wrong, as it seems to work well over here: http://sprunge.us/UTWV and http://sprunge.us/RXFY. Moreover, I can't think of any fundamental reason why the kernel wouldn't want to let you modify softirqs API. One thing to keep in mind, if you are building your module using /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build in the Makefile, then you need to build and install the modified kernel (in case you haven't, you might want to check that).